# fetch all buildings of an area in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I need to get the list of buildings of an city.

I looked up geocoder, but could not find anything to return such results.

You can suggest if this is possible via other APIs.

Comment: Which country? Or are you looking for the whole world.

Comment: Nope ! I need to look up for Indian cities.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps API doesn't offer this function. However [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) might help you. There you can get access to all data inclusive buildings.

Comment: Where it exists, yes. You are certainly not guaranteed 100% coverage and it might not be properly linked to official postal address designations, which are often jealously guarded and expensive, though I can't comment on the case in India.